# Why is 1em shorter than the default font size?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I was doing some experiments, and then I ran into this issue. I sat a `div`'s height to `1em`, and I expected the div to contain the whole height of the text within, but it did not. `1em` is my browser is `16px`.

When I did not specify the `div`'s height, it successfully contained the whole height of the text, and when inspected, it turned to be of height `19px`.

Is my understanding of `em` wrong, as I thought it should represent the default font height of the browser.

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first {
  height: 1em;
  background: green;
}
.second {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…Ù‹Ø§ Say I WantØ£Ù‘Ù‹</div>
<br />
<div class="second">Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…Ù‹Ø§ Say I WantØ£Ù‘Ù‹</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9t43kyu2/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The typographical `line-height` of a text isn't surely the actual height of the rendered text in pixels:

[image]

The `line-height` css parameter of a text contains only the height between "caps height" and the "baseline". It is on most cases `1em` on my experience and also on most non-standard sources of the net. But its standardized details are better described in @web-tiki 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736762/why-is-1em-shorter-than-the-default-font-size/33737070#33737070).

If there are characters which have parts over it or below it, they will result a text whose height (in pixels) is bigger as the line height (in pixels).

The text can have small details which are below or over the standard text line. For example, the lowest part of an *y*, or the uppest parts of a non-ascii *Ű* character. These causes continously problems in the positioning.

If you don't set the div height, it will be by default `auto`, which mean, the whole content will be in it. If you specify the div height to the actual line size, without padding, border and margin, then some pixel of your text will maybe overflow. You only didn't see it, because the default value of the `overflow` css-parameter is `visible`.

Best test for that: create a div with the following settings:

```
#divId {
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

...and copy-paste an `yŰ` into its content (but characters are also okay). You will see it clipped on both sides.

Comment: W3School's is not a standard... Find the reference in the W3 candidate recommendations rather than external websites.

Comment: @Stewartside Including official standards isn't a requirement here. Even verifiable references is only a suggestion. And long, formalized standard texts can be *less* usable for the googlers of the future, because they aren't optimized for easy understability. Do you have any reason to consider the w3schools.org as invalid to be used as reference?

Comment: @peterh You should never reference a 3rd party as the place to find "standards". If you want to use some form of easy documentation to name as "standards" then use http://www.webplatform.org/ which is setup and supported by the W3C as well as help from Adobe, Apple, Google, Facebook, Microsoft and many many more. If you really need to reference something as the proper standards, then find it in the W3 recommended candidates. W3schools is outdated in many circumstances.

Comment: @peterh, It is now clear what is going on. Thanks. But just to clarify, did you mean between the caps height and descender. Because if it was between the caps height and the baseline, then the half lower of `g` will not be shown.

Comment: @web-tiki It surprises me, but I am not sure if the community consensus would be really that w3schools.org if bad. I think the best would be to ask the community on the meta about the question, this is what I did [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310302/is-the-w3schools-org-and-acceptable-reference-usable-in-css-questions).

Comment: @web-tiki ...done, the result is that it is mainly not acceptable, I am now on to find acceptable references.

Comment: @Stewartside Ok, I accepted it (see comments above). Now I am hunting for better references and insert them into the answer.

Comment: @Ghasan Yes, it is quite possible. Try the div I've suggested in the answer, you will see that "y"s and "g" will look very, very bad.

Comment: @web-tiki Right. Afaik I'found the exact formulation for the sub-problem. :-)

Comment: @peterh I still think your approach on the issue is wrong. The line height doesn't contain "only the height between caps height and the baseline". because *1/* trying [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/0qhe6va6/) out shows it isn't working that way *2/*  the line-height can be smaller or bigger without changing the font-size. *3/* that height (in pixels) is different depending on the font family used and the user agent used to compute that font.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the second div is higher is **because of the default line-height property**. It's default value is `normal`.

> **normal**
>   Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value
>   based on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as
>   . We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2.[...]  [[source w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)]

This makes your second div `~=1.2em` high depending on your user agent. You can set it's `line-height:1em;` to see the difference :

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first {
  height: 1em;
  background: green;
}
.second {
  background: orange;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…Ù‹Ø§ Say I WantØ£Ù‘Ù‹</div>
<br />
<div class="second">Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…Ù‹Ø§ Say I WantØ£Ù‘Ù‹</div>
```